# IE8 is submitting the form to the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, file-upload

It's working in all other browsers, and it was working on IE8 before, but I did some code cleanup and moved some things around, and now its submitting this form to it's self. It's an "ajax" uploader (yes, not really ajax, but you know what I mean)

Here is the JS:

```
function file_upload($theform,item_id){
    $theform.attr('ACTION','io.cfm?action=updateitemfile&item_id='+item_id);
    if($theform.find('[type=file]').val().length > 0){
        $('iframe').one('load',function(){
            $livepreview.agenda({
                action:'get',
                id:item_id,
                type:'item',
                callback:function(json){
                    $theform.siblings('.upload_output').append('<li style="display:none" class="file-upload"><a target="blank" href="io.cfm?action=getitemfile&item_file_id='+json[0].files.slice(-1)[0].item_file_id+'">'+json[0].files.slice(-1)[0].file_name+'</a> <a style="color:red" title="Delete file?" href="#deletefile-'+json[0].files.slice(-1)[0].item_file_id+'">[X]</a></li>').children('li').fadeIn();
                    $theform.siblings('.upload_output').find('.nofiles').remove();
                }
            });
            //Resets the file input. The only way to get it cross browser compatible as resetting the val to nothing
            //Doesn't work in IE8. It ignores val('') to reset it.
            $theform.append('<input type="reset" style="display:none">').children('[type=reset]').click().remove();
        });
    }
    else{
        $.alert('No file selected');
        return false;
    }
}
/* FILE UPLOAD EVENTS */
//When they select "upload" in the modal
$('.agenda-modal .file_upload').live('submit',function(event){de
    file_upload($('.agenda-modal .file_upload'),$('.agenda-modal').attr('data-defaultitemid'));
});
```

If you didn't know, `ACTION` has to be capitalized for Firefox to work. Also, i know for sure it's submitting to it's self because the iframe shows the current page inside of it's self and all the scripts get loaded again. Also, in the `.live()`, adding `return false;` does nothing.

Here is the HTML just in case:

```
        <label>Add Attachment</label>
        <form class="file_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" action="">
            <input name="binary" id="file" size="27" type="file" /><br />
            <br><input type="submit" name="action" value="Upload" /><br />
            <iframe class="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="display:none"></iframe>
        </form>
        <label>Attachments</label>
        <ul class="upload_output">
        <li class="nofiles">(No Files Added, Yet)</li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Does the page in question contain a BASE tag?

Comment: It is not actually necessary to capitalize the name of the "action" attribute for Firefox, as a trivial test page can demonstrate.

Comment: No, it doesn't have a base tag.

It has to be capitalized for dynamically changing actions. I fought over this not working for days and someone here on stackoverflow actually pointed out you have to capitalize it.

Comment: @Pointy is correct - `action` doesn't need to be special for firefox, you can test with firebug here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/YGuhN/

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400816/firefox-only-dynamic-form-action-not-working

Thats not a dynamically added form...

Comment: @Oscar - http://jsfiddle.net/p9Z6T/2/ That's dynamically added, still works :)  Is it possible you're on an old version of jQuery?

Comment: @Nick the issue is with an `<input>` element named "action" - it confuses things.

Comment: @Pointy - Ah, that brilliant netscape move strikes again!

Comment: Weird... why would an input named action affect an attribute named action with a misc value? To a browser, they shouldn't be even closely equivalent. Good catch though!

Comment: @Oscar - `<form>` input elements are also properties, e.g. `form.action` refers to your `<input name="action">` due to an ingenious decision made by Netscape years ago.

Comment: AWH yes, NOW that makes sense... Man, good thing IE took the browser market :P

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You should `return false;` at the end of your "submit" handler.</strike>

ah - well that's hard to understand. OK well where exactly is this `<iframe>` defined? *edit* — oh duhh I see it.

*edit again* — OK I realize I'm sort-of jumping up and down on thin ice with my credibility here, but I suggest adding an "id" attribute to the `<iframe>` (with "upload_target" as the id value).  Every once in a while I figure out exactly which one of "name" and "id" is important (and when/why), but that information only lasts an hour or so before my brain perversely dismisses it. (By "important" I mean specifically with `<iframe>` elements.)

Comment: returning false makes the entire form not submit for me. It's still has to submit, just to the iframe...

Comment: Actually, you helped me and told me not too submit :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367147/ajax-upload-issues-with-jquery

Comment: Ha ha!  I thought your username sounded familiar :-)  OK I'm still looking and scratching my head a little ...

Comment: Yeah, you've helped me out a few times. and good catch on that weird Firefox thing... seems strange it'd confuse the browser. But it's good to know.

Comment: ok I updated my answer again, and I apologize if it's another wrong guess

Comment: oh and back on that old question, the `<iframe>` had an "id" value according to the code you posted - here it's a class.  You can have it be the same for "class", "name", and "id" of course.

Comment: ok ill try it out, i have a meeting in 5 mins, but when i get back ill check.

Comment: So i changed the form to also have an ID of upload_target as well as changed my jQuery selector to select #upload_target rather than .upload_target, but still, no go. :( I hope i can fix this in IE8 as thats what the City Council here is on...

Comment: OK, this is weird... if i make a button that has a click event of $(form).submit(), then it works in IE, but the "submit" event wont go off when i click the submit button...

Comment: Wait what jQuery selector references "upload_target"? I don't see that in any of the code. The `<form>` tag's "target" should be just plain "upload_target".

Comment: Hmm? Sorry, not following you, The form's tag target does reference "upload_target"? The HTML above:         <form class="file_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" action="">

Comment: Right - good. I was just confused.  Well the IE8 debugger, unlike the IE6 and 7 debugger, is actually pretty good. Maybe you can get some help from it.

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to send the form to itself.

Consider that the button is of type submit (ie submits form automatically) and that the form action is empty (ie, send it self).

However, as you've correctly done, a submit handler may cause the form to not submit at all (to which I ask, what was the point of submitting in the first place? But that's past the point)

Anyway, you should stop event propagation and return false in your event handler.

Comment: If the handler returns `false`, jQuery will assume that means for propagation to stop too. There's no reason to do both (though of course it doesn't really hurt anything).

Comment: just to try it, i added event.stopPropation() at the end of the live event. Nothing happened... the form still submits even on the other browsers.

Comment: Pointy I've had an issue with that and stopping KeyDown of input text boxes. I would suggest using both.

Comment: How about showing the iframe? I've seen issues about hidden iframes not running at all. To fix, remove style="display:hidden;" and make sure frameborder="0", width="1" and height="1"

Comment: Hmm, something else must have been modified somehow or someway... The iframe, i un-display:none'd it and when i upload something in FF or Chrome, it doesnt show inside (the JSON return doesn't), but the file is uploaded...

Comment: OK, this is weird... if i make a button that has a click event of $(form).submit(), then it works in IE, but the "submit" event wont go off when i click the submit button...